# ¿Cómo represento esto en mi Modelo con una relación de herencia?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

El modelo representa gestión de ventas, mediante las tablas `Personas`, `Funcionarios`, `Clientes`, `Sucursal`, `Venta` y demás tablas. Pero mi duda se asocia con las que acabo de mencionar. (adjunto imagen)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Las restricciones son las siguientes:**

1. Pues que un funcionario y cliente son personas claramente. (Un funcionario es UNA persona y un cliente es UNA persona).
2. Una sucursal tiene muchos funcionarios, pero un funcionario solo puede trabajar en una sucursal.
3. Un funcionario puede generar muchas ventas, y una venta estar asociada a un vendedor.

El modelo además debe responder a un par de consultas. Entre ellas esta la siguiente (y la primera que probé que no funcionó). ¿Cuántas personas son funcionarios de una sucursal?

Comentado todo lo anterior, pues deduzco que tengo un **problema y dudas respecto a la relación de herencia** que intenté hacer entre las tablas `Personas`, `Funcionarios` y `Clientes`.

Pues lo primero a notar es que, la tabla funcionarios la deje con su id único (rut, pues que no es más que el número de identificación único de cada persona en mi país, por lo tanto pk), con el cod_persona y cod_sucursal que se pueden repetir. Analizando como queda la tabla `Funcionarios` creo yo que se traduce de la siguiente manera: "Una persona puede tener asociados varios (y distintos) empleos como funcionario en más de una sucursal". Lo cual es un error, eso no es lo que pretende representar mi modelo. (además de que ni siquiera logró responder la consulta anterior).

**Entonces aquí va mi interrogante.** ¿Cómo lo soluciono? ¿Cómo realmente es una relación de herencia en este caso? ¿Cómo logro que se respeten todas las restricciones que mencioné en un principio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues realmente no tienes nada que solucionar, tu modelado de la realidad no es incorrecto. Por otra parte, la especialización a la que haces referencia, tampoco es necesario que la materialices en tablas independientes, pues la cardinalidad que has definido te permite sustituirlas por los campos que ya tienes en `Ventas` y el campo `cod_sucursal` de `Funcionarios` que perfectamente podrías propagar a `Personas`. No es que sea el mejor sitio, porque no es un atributo que comparta con `Clientes`, pero dejándolo en `NULL` ya te permitiría discriminarlo de `Funcionarios`.

Esa *herencia* o *especialización* se hace cuando `Funcionarios` y `Clientes` poseen atributos específicos que conviene registrar en tablas diferentes. Pero fíjate que incluso `rut` es común a ambos, y `cod_sucursal` cualquiera puede entender que se quede en `Personas` sin que quedarse vacío represente un despilfarro de recursos.

Te propongo, por tanto, eliminar las tablas `Clientes` y `Funcionarios`, creando los campos `rut` y `cod_sucursal` en `Personas`. Aprovechando así la cardinalidad para reducir la complejidad de tu modelo de datos. Insisto en que tal y como lo tienes no está mal, simplemente tienes más tablas porque no explotas la cardinalidad que has definido. Para que se respeten las cardinalidades no tienes más que definir índices `UNIQUE()`. En mi propuesta no te hacen falta porque esas restricciones van implícitas en el diseño.

La consulta que planteas: *¿Cuántas personas son funcionarios de una sucursal?*, la resuelves con un simple:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Personas
  WHERE cod_sucursal IS NOT NULL;
```

En tu modelo bastaría con:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Funcionarios
  WHERE cod_sucursal IS NOT NULL;
```

Para saber cuántos funcionarios tiene cada sucursal harías:

```
SELECT cod_sucursal,COUNT(*) n_funcionarios
  FROM Personas
  WHERE cod_sucursal IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY 1;
```